# (Qt or other) drag and drop data of mime-type uri-list with protocole http or ftp on Windows desktop or explorer.exe

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and drop a file from a protocol http and ftp to the Windows desktop or explorer.exe with Qt or any other library or language you use? It would be the same thing that I'm looking for.

For example: You can drag an Image using http protocol From Chrome browser and drop it to the Windows desktop.

My code works only with file:/// protocol.
This code does not work.

```
QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData;
QList<QUrl> urls;
urls.push_back(QUrl("http://localhost/test/images.jpg"));
            mime->setUrls(urls);
            drag.setMimeData(mime);
            drag.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/Image (139).jpg"));
            drag.exec(Qt::MoveAction | Qt::CopyAction);
```

But this works fine:

```
QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData;
            QList<QUrl> urls;
            urls.push_back(QUrl("file:///c:/images.jpg"));
            mime->setUrls(urls);
            drag.setMimeData(mime);
            drag.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/Image (139).jpg"));
            drag.exec(Qt::MoveAction | Qt::CopyAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save file from web to local computer (temp directory) and use method with  `file:///` protocol.

```
void MainWindow::downloadToTemp(QString p_FilePath)
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(p_FilePath)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(httpDownloadFinished()));
}

void MainWindow::httpDownloadFinished() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(QObject::sender());
    QString url = reply->url().toString();
    qDebug() << url;
    QString fileName = QDir::tempPath() + url.right(url.length() - url.lastIndexOf('/'));
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
        file.write(reply->readAll());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

        //Your file path - fileName
    }
}
```

Do not forget about error processing: [`QNetworkReply::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error-2)

Comment: I could do that but, Chrome sent only the http uri, it does not download the file than put it in the explorer.exe. It looks like the Windows system download itself the data from the http uri. What about if the image from the http is like 5Mb or other 200Mb file and the user has a slow internet connection? When the user drop the file into explorer.exe I have to show the user that the drop is Ok by showing the file in the folder even if the file has not been downloaded all the data yet.

Comment: I have this code showing that Chrome send only the uri.
`if(e->mimeData()->hasImage())
        {
            e->acceptProposedAction();
            ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(e->mimeData()->imageData().value<QImage>()));
            qDebug()<<"ok image"<< e->mimeData()->urls().first().path();
        }
else if(e->mimeData()->hasUrls())
        {
            qDebug()<<"url"<<e->mimeData()->urls().first().toDisplayString();
            e->acceptProposedAction();
        }` or maybe Windows explorer.exe accept other mimeType than uri-list that I ignore.